# Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 2000

Tags: android, root

My phone moto e (1st Gen) is rooted and i can check it with rootchecker. But still i am getting this error

> Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 2000 on typing this on adb shell
>   pm set-install-location 2

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS version is 6.0 (Marshmallow), defining permissions on Manifest is not enough now. User can enable/disable specific features on settings so you need to figure out those. This is probably the reason of your SecurityException.

Check this link out:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

It must be about writing data to external storage, probably android file system doesn't find it secure.

Check this link out as well:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106028/moving-installation-location-on-non-rooted-android-5-lollipop-device

Comment: My os version is 5.0.2(lollipop)

Comment: Second link is about lollipop devices as you can see.

Comment: My OS version is 4.4.2